# Why is a .app file read differently when selected from file selector compared to drag and drop feature in browsers?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, safari, drag-and-drop

we have a scenario where user is trying to select .app type files in mac system using a javaScript file selector and through drag and drop feature. When the .app file is selected from file selector the file is read as type file and it will be of type .zip but the same file when we try to read the file details from the drag and dropped feature using the webkitGetAsEntry for dataTransferitems the file is read as directory and not as .zip file. Can we know if this is a browser or javascript limitation for these types of file as it is not consistently read in same way as in file selector and drag and drop way. Please let us know if official documentation to state this restriction.

I have created fiddle - [`link`](https://jsfiddle.net/8r0n3w27/)

When file is selected from file selector or from the drag and drop dataTransferitems we can see the difference in how file is interpreted. I have tested this issue and it is happening in both the browsers chrome and safari.

Note:- please try to select .app files to recreate the issue.

Any help to understand this usecase is appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone help on this?